# ASP Partial View drop downs are all changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, this

Using ASP.Net Core MVC

The site contains multiple drop downs containing Hotels, once the user selects a hotel an Ajax call returns the Hotel Rooms for the selected hotel. The user can select up to 10 hotel + hotel room combinations, so each par of Hotel and Hotel Room drop downs are in a separate partial view.

When I select a Hotel from one of the partial view, all the Hotel drop down move to the same hotel.

I thought it was something in my javascript, so I commented out every related javascript, except for the call to get hotels. Here is my code:

Partial View

```
@model Cfv3.Models.Vacation.SelectHotelRoom
<select class="hotel-dropdown" name="hotel"></select>
<select class="hotelroom-dropdown" name="hotel"></select>
```

Calling the View

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.IncludedHotels.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Partial("_PossibleHotelRoom", Model.IncludedHotels[i])
        <hr/>  
    }
</div>
```

Upon load Ajax loads the hotels

```
$.get('GetHotels', function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        //console.log(value.id + " " + value.name)
        $('<option>').val(value.id).text(value.name).appendTo('.hotel-dropdown');
    });
});
```

Comment: `.appendTo('.hotel-dropdown')` is going to append to *every* matching element on the page.  You need to specifically identify which one you want to append to.  In what context is `$.get()` running?  Is it in response to some event on the page triggered by a specific element?  Such an element could be used as a starting point to traverse the DOM with jQuery to identify the specific drop down you want.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [last()](https://api.jquery.com/last/) in jquery.

```
$.get('GetHotels', function (data) {
    //console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        //console.log(value.id + " " + value.name)
        $('<option>').val(value.id).text(value.name).appendTo('.hotel-dropdown').last();
    });
});
```

**Edit:** This is just one solution to solve your current issue. I'm sure you will have many alternate solutions based on different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution, it not the cleanest, but it is working.
In the partial view I removed the name from both selectors, then created an id based upon the incoming model id.

```
@model Cfv3.Models.Vacation.SelectHotelRoom
@{ 
  var localhotelid = Model.Id + "hotel";
  var localhotelroomid = localhotelid + "room";
}
<select class="hotel-dropdown" id=@localhotelid></select>
<select class="hotelroom-dropdown" id="@localhotelroomid"></select>
```

While I didn't ask about controlling the second dropdown, it had a very similar issue, so I modified the ajax call as follows:

```
$('.hotel-dropdown').click(function (e) {
    var hotelroomid = $(this).attr('id').toString().concat('room');
    $("#".concat(hotelroomid)).empty();
    $.get('GetHotelRooms', { id: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $('<option>').val(value.id).text(value.name).appendTo("#".concat(hotelroomid));
        });
    });
});
```

I am certain there is a cleaner way, but it works.